# How do I make Facebook block a friend’s Mafia Wars updates?

Tags: facebook

I like Facebook to connect with friends, but I don't like the way their favorite games spam me.

They just keep giving me Mafia Wars updates!

Is there any way to block a friend's Mafia Wars update? Or any other Facebook game for that matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can open the game at http://apps.facebook.com/inthemafia/. Find the "Block Application" link and follow the instructions. Further updates from Mafia Wars will not be seen on your account. If you're interested in just blocking a particular user's updates, you can block the person by visiting their profile and doing the same thing on that page, however you will effectively be blocking ALL of their updates and not just their Mafia Wars updates.

Answer (score 12):

Mouse over the update and you should see a Hide button. Click it, and you should be given a choice between hiding your friend or hiding Mafia Wars. Click "Hide Mafia Wars".

Comment: I believe this will only hide the updates in the news feed. This means you will still receive requests under the "Requests" section for these games. The Block Application method is the most sure-fire way to avoid spam from these facebook games.

Answer (score 3):

This does a lot more, but you should try using the [greasemonkey script "FB Purity"](http://www.fbpurity.com/) - it cleans out all of the fluff.  Runs in FireFox, Chrome, Safari and IE.  In case your friends get into "Parking Wars" or Farmville, etc.

Comment: as Matt Katz mentioned above, F.B purity is worth a look as it automatically filters out all application and game posts, from your feed, and also makes it easier to permanently block them. Great Script! (via @mack nordstrum)

Answer (score -1):

Go to the application's page and select "Block Application" and confirm.